# Sum of atrocious numbers $p^n|(7^{p^n} + 1)$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Reviewing Fermat's Little Theorem, I came across a question on [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fermats-little-theorem/) in the applications portion of the article.

It states that a number $p^n$ is said to be atrocious if $p^n|(7^{p^n} + 1)$ where $p$ is prime. The goal is to find the sum of all atrocious numbers. The question doesn't quantify $n$, but I am assuming it is a positive integer.

***Attempt***

Fermat's Little theorem states for any prime $p$, for any integer $a$ that $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$.

Ok so suppose $p$ is a prime where $p^n$ is atrocious for some $n$, then $p|p^n$, and so $p|(7^{p^n} + 1)$. Then since $p$ is prime I want to write $7^{p^n} = (7^p)^{p^{n-1}} \equiv 7^{p^{n-1}} \pmod{p}$. Continuing on in this manner, you can show that $7^{p^n} \equiv 7 \pmod{p}$.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: You mean $(7^p)^{p^{n-1}} \equiv 7^{p^{n-1}}$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov right oops.

Comment: Don't forget the $+1$. I think we end up back at your original conclusion that $p=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first by the line of reasoning OP, $p$ has to divide $7+1$ so $p$ must be 2. Also, note the following: If $2^n|(7^{2^n} +1)$ for $n >3$ then $7^{2^n} \pmod 8 = -1$.
But then $7 \pmod 8 =-1$ already and so $7^{2^n} \pmod 8 = 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ [because the exponent $2^n$ is even for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$] so this is impossible for $2^n$ to divide $7^{2^n}$ for $n>3$, and one can check directly that it is impossible for $n=2$ as well . Thus $2^0=1, 2^1= 2$ can be the only atrocious numbers. So $1+2=3$.

Comment: Just filling in the gaps if I understand correctly. So if $n=2$, then $7^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \pmod {4}$, but since $7 \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$, then we have the same problem that simulatenously $7^{2^{n}} \pmod {4} \equiv 1$. Then for $n=0$ we have that $1$ divides any integer and for $n=1$ we have that $2 | 50$ is true.

Comment: If $n=2$ say then $7^{2^n} \pmod 8 =7^{2^2} \pmod 8 =(-1)^{2^2} =1$ so $7^{2^2} \pmod 4 =1$. You'd instead need $7^{2^2} \pmod 4$ to be $-1$. What you said in the comment above is correct for $n=0,1$.